# How long would Dalek Sec have survived?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

Dalek Sec is a human-Dalek hybrid that the Doctor faced in New York during the great depression. He was created because the Daleks felt they needed to evolve in order to survive. They practiced the genetic fusion on humans and pigs to make pig slaves, but the pig slaves were unstable, and had a very short lifespan.

Eventually, Dalek Sec gets killed by the other Daleks, but if they hadn’t killed him, how long would he have survived? Is there any canon information about this?

Comment: Seeing how the Dalek was able to force a spontaneous evolutionary change in merging with Diagoras, I'm going to go out on a limb and say "for a very long time".

Answer (score 1):

There's no in-universe description of the life-cycle or lifespan of a [Human/Dalek hybrid](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Human-Dalek).

Despite their supposed racial and genetic purity, it's not so hard to believe that they would attempt it (given the Dalek race's obsession with the human race and our immense longevity as a species) but I think we can reasonably assume that adding human DNA to Dalek DNA wouldn't result in a dramatic increase in the [normal Dalek lifespan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dalek_Emperor#Emperors_during_the_Last_Great_Time_War) of around 200+ years.

Comment: You would think that combining the DNA would result in the Human/Dalek Hybrid lifespan being the average of the two.... In the 1930's the average human life span was about 57ish for males... So if you take an average of both it would be about 129 year life span (if you round up from 128.5).

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - without a canon source, any answer is pure conjecture.

Comment: So is answering a question on here as it's not answerable legit... Or should it be closed considering there is no 100% correct answer since it has no canon sources for determining the lifespan of a hybrid of a Dalek / Human?

Comment: @doctorwho222 - No, it should be left open until a canon answer exists

Comment: The only way a canon answer is going to exist is if a writer or somebody affiliated with Doctor Who answers it... Or if an episode / valid book actually uses a new story / goes back and visits the idea of Dalek / Human Hybrid (which I doubt will happen)...

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - It's fairly likely that in the next 50 years we will see an aged human/dalek hybrid.